# How to put a value in a checkbox using Laravel?

Tags: php, forms, session, laravel

What i'm trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
<?php
        if (Session::has('tk'))
        {
            $tk = Session::get('tk');
        } else {
            $tk = 1;
        }
        if (Session::has('ntk'))
        {
            $ntk = Session::get('ntk');
        } else {
            $ntk = 0;
        }
    ?>
    {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'aanvullen')) }}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::submit('Toepassen') }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ Form::checkbox('tijdkritisch', <?php $tk ?>, true) }} Tijdkritisch (TK) <br>
                    {{ Form::checkbox('niettijdkritisch', <?php $ntk ?>, false) }} Niet-tijdkritisch (NTK)
                <td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    {{ Form::close() }}
```

Somehow in my Form::checkbox this doesn't work. So my question is how do I accomplish this?

What i've also tried was this:

```
Session::get('tk', 1);
Session::get('ntk', 0);
```

Because this way I don't need the if because it gives a default value

Comment: Change `<?php $tk ?>` to simply `$tk`, the same goes for `<?php $ntk ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, following:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('tijdkritisch', <?php $tk ?>, true) }} Tijdkritisch (TK) <br>
{{ Form::checkbox('niettijdkritisch', <?php $ntk ?>, false) }} Niet-tijdkritisch (NTK)
```

Should be changed to this:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('tijdkritisch', $tk , true) }} Tijdkritisch (TK) <br>
{{ Form::checkbox('niettijdkritisch', $ntk, false) }} Niet-tijdkritisch (NTK)
```

Remove the `<?php ?>` from `{{  }}`, also you may write the code like this:

```
$tk = Session::has('tk') ? Session::get('tk') : 1;
$ntk = Session::has('ntk') ? Session::get('ntk') : 0;
```

Or like this (Seems you are aware of this, anyways):

```
$tk = Session::get('tk', 1);
$ntk = Session::get('ntk', 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So for everyone how sees this post. Inside the {{ }} never put php tags.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha, thanks for adding the suggestion to reduce its code with `Session::get('tk', 1)`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha, Thank you for that first suggestion. That's way better than the one that I was aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put PHP tags inside blade directives, instead just put your PHP code inside the blade directive as you would do for a PHP tags:

Using blade directives:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('name', $tk, true) }}
```

Using PHP tags:

```
<?php echo Form::checkbox('name', $tk, true) ?>
```